How to change the IGPU shared VRAM
I just got a RTX 3060 12gb graphics card. My current graphics properties show as follows

I may have changed the iGPU value (i7-6600k cpu), but I am unable to remember what changes I made.
I checked that there is no GMM key in the intel node in the registry as many youtube video suggests.
Kindly do explain what I the "shared video memory" as shown in the screen shot.
What can i do to change the igpu value to the default now that I have a dedicated graphics card?
